# How to localize no-script (iframe) reCAPTCHA?

Tags: localization, recaptcha, noscript

I know that to localize the regular (JavaScript) reCAPTCHA I can provide lang attribute to Recaptcha.create method as specified in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization#i18n) I've tried to do the same for noscript version by passing lang in query string like this `http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=<key>&lang=ru`, but I still got an English version.

Does anyone know how to localize the iframe version?

Answer (score 0):

try using &hl=ru parameter.  hope this help.